# Material theme doesn't seem to work in QML

Tags: qt, themes, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I have a simple QML with an `ApplicationWindow`, `RowLayout` and a bunch of `Buttons` inside. I have applied the Qt Quick Controls 2 `Material` theme as per [the docs](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.7/qtquickcontrols2-material.html), but nothing changed. What's wrong?

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    Material.theme: Material.Dark
    Material.accent: Material.Orange

    id: window
    visible: true

    RowLayout {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: window.horizontalCenter
        anchors.bottomMargin: 32

        Button {
            text: "A"
        }

        Button {
            text: "B"
        }

        Button {
            text: "C"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use `QQmlApplicationEngine` in C++ to load the `ApplicationWindow`? It seems it is needed to control some properties from QML. See Qt documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-gettingstarted.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Importing `QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0` and setting some Material specific properties do not apply the Material theme. They will be used if the theme is set using one of the methods described here:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html

Comment: Ah! Thank you. Too bad this isn't on the page I used for reference. Qt documentation is generally good, but sometimes too fragmented.

Comment: Let me mention that there's still an error reported by Qt Creator when importing `QtQuick.Controls.Material`. This reported error is a known bug of Qt Creator and should not prevent the style from being applied. Try loading the TextEditor example. It uses QtQuick Controls 2 and shows the error in Qt Creator although it correctly uses the `qtquickcontrols2.conf` `[Material]` section parameters. See https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-54986 and https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-texteditor-example.html . I'm using Qt Creator 4.4.0 and Qt 5.9.1.